# OpenApi 3.0.2. Spec-file does not have router property

Tags: node.js, api, swagger, openapi

I'm trying to build an API using OpenApi 3.0.2 for active documentation. I've managed to build a validated spec-file, and if I take out all of the OpenApi "stuff" from the API itself, all of the routes work properly, and I have no errors (unless I've managed to change something vital while attempting to solve this problem).

Additionally, my controllers do in fact have the generic controller names that this error suggests I use, so my initial thought was that it's having trouble finding my controllers. However, when I used Swagger 2.0 (before rebuilding it with 3.0), I didn't have this problem.

All of my controllers are structured similarly, and when I changed the order of the controllers (path '/users' first), I retrieved the same error ('users' swapped out for 'garments' in the error log).

That said, I feel that there must be something I'm doing wrong in my "bringing together" of the functioning API and the valid spec-file.

I've been looking for a solution to this problem for a while now, but I have found nothing. If this question has been asked and answered before, I apologize; please redirect me. This is my first StackOverflow question, so please be gentle. If I have missed any information important to the question, please let me know.

Error:

```
outfittr | 2019-01-21T13:51:37.150Z info: Valid specification file
outfittr | 2019-01-21T13:51:37.162Z info: Specification file dereferenced
outfittr | 2019-01-21T13:51:37.210Z info: No localhost or relative server found in spec file, added for testing in Swagger UI
outfittr | 2019-01-21T13:51:37.210Z debug: Register: GET - /garments
outfittr | 2019-01-21T13:51:37.211Z debug:   GET - /garments
outfittr | 2019-01-21T13:51:37.212Z debug:     Spec-file does not have router property -> try generic controller name: garmentsController
outfittr | 2019-01-21T13:51:37.212Z debug:     Controller with generic controller name wasn't found either -> try Default one
outfittr | 2019-01-21T13:51:37.212Z error:     There is no controller for GET - /garments
outfittr exited with code 0
```

openapi.yaml:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: Outfittr API

paths:

  /swagger:
    x-swagger-pipe: swagger_raw

####################################### Garments ##############################################

  /garments:
    x-router-controller: garmentsController
    get:
      description: Returns an array of garments.
      operationId: indexGarments
      responses:
        "200":
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Garment'
        default:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"
    post:
      summary: Creates a new garment
      operationId: newGarment
      description: Adds garment to the system
      responses:
        '200':
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Garment'
        default:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Garment'
        description: User that was created.

  /garments/{_id}:
    x-router-controller: garmentsController
    get:
      description: Returns one garment
      operationId: viewGarment
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: _id
          schema:
            type: string
          required: true
          description: Numeric ID of the user to get
      responses:
        "200":
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Garment'
        default:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"


######################################## Users ################################################

  /users:
    x-router-controller: usersController
    get:
      description: Returns an array of users.
      operationId: indexUsers
      responses:
        "200":
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
        default:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"
    post:
      summary: Creates a new user
      operationId: newUser
      description: Adds user to the system
      responses:
        '200':
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
        default:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
        description: User that was created.

  /users/{_id}:
    x-router-controller: usersController
    get:
      description: Returns one user
      operationId: viewUser
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: _id
          schema:
            type: string
          required: true
          description: Numeric ID of the user to get
      responses:
        "200":
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
        default:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"

####################################### Wardrobe ##############################################

  /wardrobe:
    x-router-controller: wardrobeController
    get:
      description: Returns an array of garments in the user's wardrobe.
      operationId: indexWardrobeItems
      responses:
        "200":
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/WardrobeItem'
        default:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"
    post:
      summary: Creates a new wardrobe item
      operationId: newWardrobeItem
      description: Adds garment to the user's wardrobe in the system
      responses:
        '200':
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/WardrobeItem'
        default:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/WardrobeItem'
        description: User that was created.

  /wardrobeItem/{_id}:
    x-router-controller: wardrobeController
    get:
      description: Returns one wardrobe item
      operationId: viewWardrobeItem
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: _id
          schema:
            type: string
          required: true
          description: Numeric ID of the user to get
      responses:
        "200":
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/WardrobeItem'
        default:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"

###################################### Components #############################################

servers:
  - url: outfittr.net
  - url: localhost:3000
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      required:
        - _id
        - email
        - username
        - password
      properties:
        _id:
          type: string
          description: unique ID given by Mongo.
        firstName:
          type: string
          description: First name of the user.
        lastName:
          type: string
          description: Last name of the user.
        email:
          type: string
          description: User's email address.
        username:
          type: string
          description: User's username (for login)
        password:
          type: string
          description: User's password (for login).
        create_date:
          type: string
          description: date that the user joined.
        __v:
          type: integer
          description: I have no idea.

    Garment:
      type: object
      required:
        - _id
        - type
        - imageLink
      properties:
        _id:
          type: string
          description: unique ID given by Mongo.
        type:
          type: string
          description: type of garment
        imageLink:
          type: string
          description: primary color of garment
        __v:
          type: integer
          description: I have no idea.

    WardrobeItem:
      type: object
      required:
        - _id
        - owner_id
        - garment_id
      properties:
        _id:
          type: string
          description: unique ID given by Mongo.
        unavailable:
          type: boolean
          description: Is the wardrobe item dirty, loaned out, or otherwise unavailable?
        owner_id:
          type: string
          description: foreign key linking this wardrobe item to its owner.
        garment_id:
          type: string
          description: foreign key linking this wadrobe item to the garment it is.
        torn:
          type: boolean
          description: Is the wardrobe item torn?
        reserveDate:
          type: string
          description: Optional - a date for which this wardrobe item must be worn
        reserveTilDate:
          type: string
          description: Optional - a date after which the wardrobe item cannot be worn until the reserveDate.
        __v:
          type: integer
          description: I have no idea.

    ErrorResponse:
      required:
        - message
      properties:
        message:
          type: string
```

Any help is vastly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this even if it's late because I have had this same problem and looked for a long time the solution. If someone else happens to have any reference on how to fix it.

When you set the controllers parameter in oas-tools:

```
OasTools.configure({
    controllers: `${__dirname}/controllers`,
    ...
});
```

The default mapping that oas-tools makes to load the files is `endpoint+Controller.js`, in your case `oas-tools` would look for the export function `indexGarments` in `.../controllers/garmentsController.js`

Another example would be for the case `/garments/{_ id}`, the name of the controller file should be `garments_idController.js`

### Using x-router-controller

If you want to use the parameter `x-router-controller` you have to put it inside the method:

```
...
  /garments:
    get:
      x-router-controller: garmentsController
      operationId: indexGarments
      description: Returns an array of garments.
      responses:
```

***But be careful*** because it also modifies the value of the parameter (I do not know if this is a bug or because the name of the files has that requirement), for example, if you configure `x-router-controller` with the value `garments.resource` the file to be searched will be `.../controllers/garmentsresource.js`

In case you set the `x-router-controller` parameter and the file is not found, this error will be thrown:

```
info: Valid specification file
info: Specification file dereferenced
debug: Register: GET - /health
debug:   GET - /health
debug:     OAS-doc has x-router-controller property
error: undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

For OAS3 you may try this:

```
paths:
  /users:
    get:
      tags:
        - User
      
      x-openapi-router-controller: usersController
      description: Returns an array of users.
      operationId: indexUsers
      responses:
        "200":
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
```